# Shell script for partial table backup

Tags: mysql, mysqldump, scripting

I have multiple database in my MYSQL server and i want to take some particular tables backup from each database.
    can anyone help me in writting a shell script for this scenario.

Answer (score 1):

write table names in a file and use following command to take backups

> for i in `cat table_name_file` 
>   do
>   mysqldump -uroot -p -T $i
>   done

Hope it helps